# Qt Send the given keys to the active application

Tags: c++, windows, qt

I have been looking without success to any Qt class that has methods to send keys to MS **Windows** desktop OS active application, I wonder if there is straight solution. What I want is something similar to VS Clr/C++ class  `System::Windows::Forms::SendKeys` which has the ethod `SendWait(String^)`.

Comment: Qt does not have classes to send keystrokes/mouse motions to other applications. You need to fall back to platform-dependent APIs. Please edit your question and include the platform you are targeting so that people here can help you...

Comment: @Mike, No problem, it was indicated though `System::Windows`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Under windows using `SendInput` from `user32` library with Qt is direct and simple like this:

> .pro

```
win32: LIBS += -lUser32
```

a function can take an arbitrary keys to be re-transmitted:

> .cpp

```
#include "Windows.h"
// Because the SendInput function is only supported in
// Windows 2000 and later, WINVER needs to be set as
// follows so that SendInput gets defined when windows.h
// is included below.
#define WINVER 0x0500
void sendKeys::sendKeysqt(QString bCodeSequence)
{
    // This structure will be used to create the keyboard
    // input event.
    int arraySizeqtt = bCodeSequence.length();
    INPUT ip;
    // Pause for 2 seconds.
    Sleep(2000);
    for (int i=0; i < arraySizeqtt; i++)
    {
        // Set up a generic keyboard event.
        ip.type = INPUT_KEYBOARD;
        ip.ki.wScan = 0; // hardware scan code for key
        ip.ki.time = 0;
        ip.ki.dwExtraInfo = 0;

        // Press the key
        byte x = VkKeyScan(bCodeSequence.at(i).unicode());
        ip.ki.wVk = x; // virtual-key code for the "a" key
        ip.ki.dwFlags = 0; // 0 for key press
        SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));

        // Release the key
        ip.ki.dwFlags = KEYEVENTF_KEYUP; // KEYEVENTF_KEYUP for key release
        SendInput(1, &ip, sizeof(INPUT));
    }
}
```